# Has the @reply matching rule changed, so that a complete match is considered valid regardless of word boundaries?

Tags: support, comment-replies

I have a comment<sup>*</sup> notification in my inbox that says:

> @entoさん、了解しました。

I thought that this will not be a valid @reply; the whole "@entoさん、了解しました。" string will be considered as a @name, since the CJK characters are valid characters in display names, and according to the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/157841):

> neither @alix nor @aliceinwonderland will match user Alice

Is @aliceinwonderland considered a match for Alice now?

Or maybe there's something more going on behind the scenes to handle CJK characters? What are the exact rules then?

<sub><sup>*</sup>I've checked and the comment has not been edited.</sub>